# Stop lag on calling scroll function with webkit filter javascript

Tags: javascript, scroll

I have this function being called everytime the page is scrolled by a user:

```
window.onscroll=function(){
   document.getElementById("navBlurContent").style.top=-window.pageYOffset+125+"px";
}
```

However, this causes lots of lag to the browser. I have noticed some answers with jQuery that calls a delay to when the function is called. But, I want to use strictly javascript. I was wondering how this could this be done.

I have now realized that the majority of the lag is being caused by a -webkit-filter I have on the element. But I am not sure how to stop it.

Thanks

Comment: In modern browsers it seems you could use position:fixed

Comment: The actual nav itself is position:fixed; But this is a seperate fixed element under it that has all of my pages content in it with a webkit filter on it. Im pretty sure this webkit filter is creating all of the lag. I just don't know how to fix it.

Comment: So the real problem is that I have to apply this webkit filter to all of my elements. Which causes a huge amount of lag.

Comment: If you have two main elements on the page and both position:fixed then I don't understand why you need window.onscroll in the first place

Answer (score 2):

Try not to do a DOM select on every scroll.

Cache it:

```
var blur_content = document.getElementById("navBlurContent");
window.onscroll=function(){
   blur_content.style.top=-window.pageYOffset+125+"px";
};
```

Comment: @user1938671: *"I just what was causing the lag even more"* Say what now?

Comment: @user1938671: There will always be lag if you're doing this with JavaScript, Neal's answer just helps you *minimize* that lag. Ideally, on modern browsers, do this with CSS instead.

Comment: the real problem is with the CSS webkit filter I have enplace. Sorry about the writing before, was rushing to type it.

Comment: I thought of the same approach (caching the DOM search) so I put this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/33Egb/) to time the difference, which is really not that big, since getting elements by id is pretty fast in most JavaScript implementation. For a 10000 runs I get 269ms  (without caching) vs. 248ms (with caching), which is less than a 10% improvement.